# Creating 2-D array in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am new to ruby and trying to create a 2D array
I don't want to use any lib and the good expression

```
mat = Array.new(rows){ Array.new(cols) }
```

instead like a C way declaring A 2d array first mat[[]]

```
mat = Array.new(rows)
i = rows
while i > 0
    mat[i].push(Array.new(cols) )
    i -=1
end
```

It gives error because of `mat[[]]`, saying  undefined local variable or method `mat' for main:Object (NameError)

when i remove the declarion it creates matrix as `[1,2,[][]]`

Assume rows and cols are passed

What is the way to do

Comment: Could you show the final array you're trying to create?

Comment: Ruby doesn't have 2D arrays (unless you make a stretch and include `Matrix`), Ruby has arrays-of-arrays though.

Comment: Please provide an example of the result that you need. Also please take the time to format the question so it is more readable. Questions that are hard to read and understand get a lot less help; People interpret your effort into their willingness to help.

Comment: I'd like to have an explanation of why you wouldn't consider `Matrix` in the standard library, or any other library.

Answer (score -1):

```
rows = 5
cols = 3

mat = Array.new(rows)
i = rows
while i >= 0 
  mat[i] = (Array.new(cols) )
  i -=1
end

p mat # => [[nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil]]
```

Comment: you should share the output

Comment: Yeah and what you've changed/why

Comment: @KalmanHazins - I did was not the one downvoting, but just pasting in some code is not very helpful - a few sentences about _how_ this solves the problem goes a long way to teach someone this is new to.

Comment: @UriAgassi take a chill man. :) He already knew what he wanted and I just got him past his syntax error

Comment: I didn't vote, but the code isn't written in the Ruby-way, which could garner a down-vote. Showing an answer that works is ok, but showing an idiomatic answer that works is the better thing.

Comment: @theTinMan I agree with you, but the guy specifically asked for the C way declaration style which will work in Ruby. Whoever downvoted clearly didn't look at the whole picture.

Comment: The OP can ask for that, but it's still OK to point out that the Ruby way is to be preferred. Writing code that is idiomatic makes the developer fit into a production environment and be a member of a team, rather than a misfit whose code has to be refactored just to be maintained.

Comment: Again, not disagreeing with you in principle. It's that old "walk before you run" thing...

Answer (score -2):

I did it like this

```
mat = []
  rows.times do |r| 
    mat[r] = []
    cols.times do |c| 
      mat[r][c] 
    end
  end
```

Comment: This didn't do what you think it did. Did you check the resulting `mat`?

Answer (score -3):

Array.new(i, Array.new) where 'i' is the number of arrays you'd like to embed.

Ex:

```
 Array.new(3, Array.new)
 returns  `=> `[[], [], []]`.
```

You can even specify the values you'd like within the embedded arrays:

Ex:

```
Array.new(3, Array.new(3, Array.new(3, "HEY"))
 => [[["HEY", "HEY", "HEY"], ["HEY", "HEY", "HEY"], ["HEY", "HEY", "HEY"]], [["HEY", "HEY", "HEY"], ["HEY", "HEY", "HEY"], ["HEY", "HEY", "HEY"]], [["HEY", "HEY", "HEY"], ["HEY", "HEY", "HEY"], ["HEY", "HEY", "HEY"]]]
```

Comment: And then do `array.first << 42` and see what happens. Gotta use the block!